# woocommerce single product page half load

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

woocommerce Single page product not load completely, however some other pages are loading perfectly but some are not opening. I've checked the error log page and found these 02 errors lines.

my page link
https://echno.com/shop/ultrastar-c10k900-600gb-sas/

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/echno.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1889\n', referer: https://echno.com/wp-admin/edit.php?s=ULTRASTAR+C10K900+600GB+SAS&post_status=all&post_type=product&action=-1&seo_filter&readability_filter&product_type&stock_status&paged=1&action2=-1

AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/echno.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1889\n', referer: https://echno.com/shop/ultrastar-c10k900-600gb-sas/
```

My server and woocommerce details are as followed:

1. PHP version:        7.1.15
2. WP memory limit:        512 MB
3. PHP post max size:      32 MB
4. PHP max input vars:     1000
5. WC version:     3.3.3
6. WP version:     4.9.4
7. Total Database Size     738.17MB
8. Database Data Size      455.29MB
9. Database Index Size     282.88MB

Comment: turn on wordpress debug mode and also provide its logs

Comment: **' Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in /var/www/vhosts/echno.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-term.php on line 199 '**

got this error also enabled debug mode you can check by clicking above mentioned site link